# Spring Data REST: How to retrieve many items using list of Ids in one single call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I can retrieve one single book from Spring Data REST  with a call such as:
    GET /book/{id}

Now, if I know the Ids of two books and I want to retrieve them all at once? What should the call be? I tried the following but it is returning me different books than the specified ones:

```
GET /book?ids=id1,id2
```

Comment: you need to contact the owner of service to apprise *OR* is it something you expect from SO users to help you design one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could declare a query method in your Repository interface like this:

```
List<Book> findByIdIn(@Param("ids") Long[] ids);
```

So that you can request books this way:

```
GET /book/search/findByIdIn?ids=1,6,9
```

Comment: That works thanks a lot. IS there any documentation on the In suffix that you added to findById?

Comment: I don't know if there is documentation about that. I even didn't find. I use to follow Spring Tools Suite suggestions (just type 'findBy' and press Ctrl+space in your JPA interface).