# How to return representations of associations in a Spring Data REST resource?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

There are following URLS - /users/2/profile , /users/2/userPosts

I need to concat output of both Spring Data REST results in server side and build single JSON from them and send on different URL `/users/2/custom`.

So, I am thinking to make 2 calls to SDR urls from Spring MVC, can we do this using RestTemplate and some JSON concat utility , here server and database is on same machine so RestTemplate will probably have localhost

An example will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might rather want to look into the projections feature of Spring Data REST which allows you to craft custom responses by using interfaces as described in this [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra#user-content-projections-in-spring-data-rest).

As both properties (`profile` and `userPosts`) seem to be associations of a user item resource it should be sufficient to do something like this:

```
@Projection(types = User.class)
interface UserWithDetails {

  // List getters for basic properties you want to expose…

  // Add dedicated getters for associations to be included

  Profile getProfile();

  List<Post> getUserPosts();
}
```

Clients can now pass a `projection` parameter to the resources exposed to see the expanded representation.

As an alternative, you can create these kinds of interfaces for `Profile` and `Post` and configure `@RepositoryRestResource` on the repositories for both of these types to contain `excerptProjection = YourProjectionInterface.class`. This will cause the projections to be rendered whenever an association is included in the response (i.e. an actually-linked-to-resource could be embedded).

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, I have a question however If I add Excerpt projections to ProfileRespository and UserPostRepository , will I be still able to create/update new Profile and Post records using PUT/PATCH requests from these URL - /profiles and /userPosts

Comment: Second doubt is there as well, when I make a repository an Excerpt projection, I find that associations are indeed embedded in Entities.  To give an example at one point of time I created UserRepository itself an Excerpt projection. And since UserPost and Profile have user object, they show User projetion data by default. Is there any way I can hide this projected data from coming userpost and profile. I tried @JsonIgnore on User but it did not help

Comment: No, excerpt projections are applied *everywhere* an association is embedded. I'd generally recommend to avoid bi-directional relationships in this scenario as all of your three concepts are basically aggregate roots (due to being managed by a repository) and it's harder to enforce aggregate consistency if bi-directional relationships are used.

If you selectively want to apply the merge on the user side only, go with the first suggestion and craft a projection for `User` so that clients have dedicated control over when to use it or not.

Comment: I implemented with Option 1 and am running into pagination Issue since it is embedding all data in Projection. Everything other than that is alright. I had figured out a solution before using SPring MVC URL forwarding and am clueless here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539550/use-case-for-pagination-of-embedded-resources

Comment: I am just thinking on the lines of having Page<Post> getUserPosts(); in UserWithDetails