# RestResource: get id of subentity without extra request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have entities like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    Long id;
    SecondEntity second;
    ...
}

@Entity
class SecondEntity {
    Long id;
    ...
}
```

I use @RestResource for rest-API.
If I request list of MyEntity I get result like:

```
{
    "_links": {
      "self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/1"},
      "second": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/1/second"}
    }
},
{
    "_links": {
      "self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/2"},
      "second": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/2/second"}
    }
}
```

If I want check, is [0].second == [1].second, I need to do two extra request. It is not good.

Maybe possible to configure RestResource that it gave the following resource?

```
{
    "_links": {
      "self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/1"},
      "second": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/SecondEntity/12"}
    }
},
{
    "_links": {
      "self": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/MyEntity/2"},
      "second": {"href": "http://localhost:8080/api/SecondEntity/45"}
    }
}
```

Comment: The data you need (id of subentity) can only be obtained from the response of a REST request. So you will have to send 2 requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using projections feature of Spring Data REST

Here is an explanation https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra#user-content-projections-in-spring-data-rest

Here is a similar question [How to return representations of associations in a Spring Data REST resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795184/how-to-return-representations-of-associations-in-a-spring-data-rest-resource)

Comment: Yes. It suitable for me. Thank you!